# Vertical Text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, vertical-text

I'm looking to vertically align text by adding `<br />` tags between characters with jQuery.

```
<div id="foo"><label>Vertical Text</label></div>
```

would look like this:

V
e
r
t
i
c
a
l

T
e
x
t

Answer (score 26):

Let's go golfing!

```
$('#foo label').html($('#foo label').text().replace(/(.)/g,"$1<br />"));
```

Completely untested, but the pattern in the regex looks like a boob.

Answer (score 4):

Mr Kurt's answer works well for a single id, but if you want something more useful that can be applied to several elements try something like this:

`$.each( $(".verticalText"), function () { $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(.)/g, "$1<br />")) } );`

Then just set `class="verticalText"` on the elements you want to be formatted like this.

And as a bonus it keeps the boob regex.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but it should work.

```
var element = $( '#foo label' );
var newData = '';
var data = element.text();
var length = data.length;
var i = 0;

while( i < length )
{

    newData += data.charAt( i ) + '<br />';
    i++;

}

element.html( newData );
```

Comment: V<br />e<br />r<br />t<br />i<br />c<br />a<br />l<br /> <br />T<br />e<br />x<br />t<br /> is what that makes.

Comment: That last line needs to be: element.html( newData );

Comment: Indeed.  That is better than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`document.write("vertical text".split("").join("<br/>"));`

Edit:
Hole in one!

Answer (score 1):

This builds on Sebastian H's answer, but I tested it and this works

```
    var element = $( '#foo label' );
    var newData = '';
    var data = element.text();
    var length = data.length;
    var i = 0;
    $( '#foo label' ).html("");
    while( i < length )
    {
            $( '#foo label' ).append(data.charAt( i ) + "<br />")
            i++;
    }
```

Comment: If i have more then one it seems to append to both, thus doubling the text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a while loop when you can use jQuery's builtin each method?

`$.each(
               $('#foo').text(), function(){
                                     $('#foo').append(this + '
');
                                 }
        );`

There. It works. You can test it.