# Vertical Text Direction

Tags: html, css, text, vertical-alignment

I have been trying text to go in a vertical direction like we can do in ms-word tables but so far I have only been able to do [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/e3c5Q/)... which I am not happy with because it's a box rotated... Isn't there a way to have actual vertical direction text?

I only set the rotation to 305 degrees in the demo which doesn't make the text vertical. `270deg` will but I only made the demo to show rotation.

Comment: Hello, could you review your accepted answer to fit with a non obsolete syntax to improve quality. Your question is seen as a duplicate,

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Alternative approach: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css

```
p { writing-mode: tb-rl; }
```

Comment: I was able to find this: http://generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes. Though it feels so hacky.

Comment: @CrystalMiller and BTW, w3schools can be a good helper, but it is not the source/original documentation (so it can miss some things), the "official" is w3.org, or the closest, more human-readable, to it is mozilla's developer network - "MDN" - https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: It works in chrome, mozilla and IE edge  but not safari for windows.

Comment: `tb-rl` is deprecated, please use `vertical-rl` instead.

Comment: sadly, if the vertical text is on the left side of the screen, most roman texts are read bottom-to-top. And then top-to-bottom if the text is on the right side of the screen. Having some values deprecated, we end up with the sole vertical-rl that is top to bottom for the right side of the screen. For the left side, we have to add a transform: rotate(180deg);

Comment: I am using writing-mode:vertical-lr; but in FF it still works wierd, can see example here: https://www.efsdk.com/help/exm/tab.htm

Answer (score 89):

```css
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

The other answers are correct but they led to some alignment problems. On trying out different things this CSS piece code worked perfectly for me.

```css
.vertical{
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: The property 'bottom' has no value without a property of 'position'.

Comment: I needed to add -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); to get this working in IE11

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode, `writing-mode:tb-rl;` is deprecated. Use `writing-mode:vertical-rl` instead!

Answer (score 82):

I was searching for an actual vertical text and not the rotated text in HTML as shown below. So I could achieve it by using the following method.

[image]

**HTML:-**

```
<p class="vericaltext">
Hi This is Vertical Text!
</p>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.vericaltext{
 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 text-orientation: upright;
}
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cguroo/hfs4r5j4/1513/)

======================= OLD Answer ==========================

**HTML:-**

```
<p class="vericaltext">
Hi This is Vertical Text!
</p>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.vericaltext{
    width:1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; /* this is just for good looks */
}
```

[**JSFiddle! Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cguroo/hfs4r5j4/1/)

**Update:-** If you need the **whitespaces** to be displayed, then add the following property to your css.

`white-space: pre;`

So, the css class shall be

```
.vericaltext{
    width:1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; /* this is just for good looks */
    white-space: pre;/* this is for displaying whitespaces */
}
```

**[JSFiddle! Demo With Whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/hfs4r5j4/14/)**

**Update 2** (28-JUN-2015)

Since  `white-space: pre;` doesnt seem to work (for this specific use) on Firefox(as of now), just change that line to

`white-space: pre-wrap;`

So, the css class shall be

```
.vericaltext{
    width:1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; /* this is just for good looks */
    white-space:pre-wrap; /* this is for displaying whitespaces including Moz-FF.*/
}
```

[**JsFiddle Demo FF Compatible.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfs4r5j4/108/)

Comment: Can I make the text align vertically centre?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean by aligning center, but maybe you can just align the container element `.vericaltext` to the center?

Comment: Another possible solution to the same result:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136214/3934058

Thanks for the tip with space ;)

Comment: info about how the answer evolved over time as it might be useful for someone to understand better. also I believe the image is better for ux as people don't have to click the `run code snippet` button to look at what this answer has to offer

Answer (score 28):

To rotate text 90 degrees:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Also, it appears that the span tag can't be rotated without being set to display:block.

Comment: <span> probably needs to be with display:block; to rotate properly

Comment: I applied this to a <div> that sits inside a <td>. It seems to successfully rotate in all browsers. ... ... BUT, once the div rotates (90degrees), the td does Not expand its height.

Answer (score 19):

To display text in vertical (Bottom-top) we can simply use:

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 

transform: rotate(180deg);
```

```css
#myDiv{
text-align: center;
}

#mySpan{
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"> 

<span id="mySpan"> Here We gooooo !!! </span>

</div>
```

Note we can add this to ensure Browser Compatibility:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);   
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

we can also read more about **`writing-mode`** property here on [Mozilla docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

Answer (score 13):

For vertical text with characters one below another in firefox use:

```
text-orientation: upright;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
writing-mode: lr-tb;
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
#myDiv{
text-align: center;
}

#mySpan{
writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"> 

<span id="mySpan"> Here We gooooo !!! </span>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm new at this, it helped me a lot. Just change width, height, top and left to make it fit:

```
.vertical-text {
display: block;
position:absolute;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

You can also go [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text) and see another way to do it. The author does it like this:

```
.vertical-text {
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: left top 0;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: transform-origin is what I needed!

Comment: float left is what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of some SVG code I used to get three lines of vertical text into a table column heading. Other angles are possible with a bit of tweaking. I believe most browsers support SVG these days.

```
<svg height="150" width="40">
  <text font-weight="bold" x="-150" y="10" transform="rotate(-90 0 0)">Jane Doe</text>
  <text x="-150" y="25" transform="rotate(-90 0 0)">0/0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0/0</text>
  <text x="-150" y="40" transform="rotate(-90 0 0)">2015-06-06</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You do with this too...

```
.p{
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   text-orientation: upright;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

rotation, like you did, is the way to go - but note that not all browsers support that. if you wan't to get a cross-browser solution, you'll have to generate pictures for that.

Answer (score 2):

Can use CSS3 Transform property

```
.txtdiv{
  transform:rotate(7deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.93969262, M12=0.34202014, M21=-0.34202014, M22=0.93969262,sizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE6-8 */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the class

```
.rotate {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

I use this pretty much everyday and not had any issues whatsoever with it.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Answer (score 2):

I've manage to have a working solution with this :

(I have a title within a middleItem class div)

```
.middleItem > .title{
    width: 5px;
    height: auto;
    word-break:break-all;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same with the below CSS properties:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an alignement like

```
S
T
A
R
T
```

Then follow https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/#upright-latin

Example:

```css
div.vertical-sentence{
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; /* for IE */
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* for Webkit */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  
}
.rotate-characters-back-to-horizontal{ 
  -webkit-text-orientation: upright;  /* for Webkit */
  text-orientation: upright; 
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-sentence">
  <p><span class="rotate-characters-back-to-horizontal" lang="en">Whatever</span></p>
  <p><span class="rotate-characters-back-to-horizontal" lang="fr">Latin</span></p>
  <p><span class="rotate-characters-back-to-horizontal" lang="hi">वर्डप्रेस </span></p>
</div>
```

Note the Hindi has an accent in my example and that will be rendered as a single character. That's the only issue I faced with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to use `writing-mode`
`writing-mode: vertical-rl;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

It defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

It has good browser support, but will not work on IE8 (if you care about IE)
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode

Answer (score 1):

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        h2 {
           margin: 0 0 0 0;
           transform: rotate(270deg);
           transform-origin: top left;
           color: #852c98;
           position: absolute;
           top: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h2>It’s all in the curd</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can change transform: rotate(270deg); to transform: rotate(90deg); according to requirements

Answer (score 1):

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

The text-orientation CSS property sets the orientation of the text characters in a line. It only affects text in vertical mode (when writing-mode is not horizontal-tb). It is useful for controlling the display of languages that use vertical script, and also for making vertical table headers.

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: mixed;
```

You can also review all the Syntax here

```
/* Keyword values */
text-orientation: mixed;
text-orientation: upright;
text-orientation: sideways-right;
text-orientation: sideways;
text-orientation: use-glyph-orientation;

/* Global values */
text-orientation: inherit;
text-orientation: initial;
text-orientation: unset;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Comment: Duplicate answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482721/1549818 2 years earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use word-wrap:break-word to get vertical text
use following snippete

HTML:

```
<div class='verticalText mydiv'>Here is your text</div>
```

css:

```
.verticalText {
word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.mydiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #text_orientation{
        writing-mode:tb-rl;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        white-space:nowrap;
        display:block;
        bottom:0;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="text_orientation">Welcome</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1{word-break:break-all;display:block;width:40px;}
```

## H E L L O

**NOTE: Browser Supported**
- IE browser (8,9,10,11)
- Firefox browser (38,39,40,41,42,43,44)
- Chrome browser (44,45,46,47,48)
- Safari browser (8,9)
- Opera browser (Not Supported)
- Android browser (44)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an SVG file, it seems to have better browser compatibility, and won't break your responsive designs.

I tried the CSS transform, and had much trouble with the transform-origin; and ended up going with an SVG file. It took like 10 minutes, and I could control it a bit with CSS too.

You can use Inkscape to make the SVG if you don't have Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but cross browser solution which requires no CSS

```html
<div>
  <div>h</div>
  <div>e</div>
  <div>l</div>
  <div>l</div>
  <div>o</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);   
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

writing-mode: vertical-rl; gives u the right vertical text