# HTML vertical text in cell + export to excel

Tags: html, excel, text

I have try to do this once, but unsuccessfully, and now meet the same problem again.

I have to generate HTML table with vertical text like this:

[image]

and this HTML should be valid(the same) in excel.

Has anyone done this?

Something more - I am not able to use images too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Text Direction - Vertical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/css-text-direction-vertical)

Comment: @Truth There are a lot of examples how to rotate the text, but I want a way working in Excel too.

Comment: did you try formatting text vertically in excel and then save as html to see the styles needed?

Comment: Why don't you generate proper xls instead of HTML?

Comment: `I have to generate HTML table with vertical text` using what technology? VBA?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Do not make me laugh please, if you have an idea or new a technique, tell it, stop flood with unnecessary comments the topic in order to look wise, because you are far away from this.

Comment: @JP, I am using javascript/jQuery only.

Comment: @deathApril, yes that was the first thing I did. The result is strange consequence of symbols.

Comment: @Joro and? does it work when you reuse this strange consequence of symbols or what do you expect from SO users to help you with??

Comment: @deathApril I thought that it is possible to do this with HTML tags - like the "color" tag. Now, I belived that I have to change the code that we use to convert the HTML code in excel format. So, I think that there is not easy way to do this, especially only with html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done using HTML only.

Comment: its possible with this css


-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
mso-rotate:90;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with this css:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
mso-rotate: 90;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
position: absolute;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

Comment: http://fabianmejia.blogspot.com/2008/11/rotate-text-in-web-generated-excel-file.html

Answer (score 1):

The following property will do the job if you want to rotate your text:

```
<td style="mso-rotate:90;">I Rotate</td>
```

http://fabianmejia.blogspot.pe/2008/11/rotate-text-in-web-generated-excel-file.html

Comment: Thanks for translating your answer to English! For future references, normally you should be able to vote to undelete your answer after you edited it (like you did in your other answer). Though I have no clue if you need a certain amount of reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
         <td style="mso-rotate:90;">No</td>
         <td style="mso-rotate:90;">Name</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this might work, it will help the OP and any further readers of this question understand the principals.