# ExtJS Label orientation

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

How do I make an ExtJS [Label](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Label) rendered horizontally as in:

```
------------
-          -
------------
```

render vertically as in:

```
----
-  -
-  -
-  -
----
```

*including the text within* it of course.

In css I would set the text's style using `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` to write the text in the appropriate direction ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779632/1211429)). But in this case, in order for the components housing the label to render at the proper size, I need to change the direction of the whole container.

Therefore, is this possible in ExtJS 4.1+? If yes, how? A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this with ExtJS, you need to draw the text item at 90 degrees:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Panel with VerticalTextItem',
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    lbar: {
        layout: {
            align: 'center'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'text',
            text: 'Sample VerticalTextItem',
            degrees: 90
        }]
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

This creates a panel with a text item rotated to 90°. This code sample can be found in the [ExtJS documentation on Ext.draw.Text](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Text), and is available in 4.1.0 and later. [Here's a fiddle of the above code as requested.](http://jsfiddle.net/H5h7D/)