# how to write/show text vertical?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to transform text according as described below.

**02 Matchday**

to

```
0
2
M
a
t
c
h
d
a
y
```

my codes are given below.. the current result is not accurate as i want. 
Kindly suggest me.

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
 td span {display:block;}
.sideways {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 transform: rotate(270deg);
}
/*put specifics here*/
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) {background-color:tomato;}
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2) {background-color:red;}
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(3) {background-color:chocolate;}
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(4) {background-color:black;}
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(5) {background-color:grey;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"><span class="sideways">O2 Matchday</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>My O2 for Windows</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Blipdrop</td>
    <td>My O2 for business</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Text Direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)

Comment: you can wrap every character with a element and do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/39snxjok/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1013/

**CSS**:

```
div {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
    <div>Sample Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved by using

```
width: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

instead of

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
```

Here is the working fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yd99nx5/)

-- Help :)