# Horizontally align rotated text

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, webkit-transform

I would like to horizontally center align some texts that have been rotated 90 and 270 degrees (following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)) with their neighboring div (whose height can change in my application).  Some of the usual tricks don't seem to work because the elements are created and processed horizontally, and then rotated.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Animik/ek1gcyv9/2/) demonstrating the problem.  Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
  <div class="vertical_left">
    <h3>Text to align</h3>  <!-- horizontally center this to the following div -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical_left{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to position it...that's what's usually required.

Comment: means you want the text to set at center vertically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "position it".  The big div in the center is actually dynamically resizable in my application, so I cannot hardcode the height.