# How I can rotate the columnNames vertically in Java?

Tags: java, rotation, grid, vaadin

Using Vaadin 8.0.7, is it somehow possible to rotate the column headers in a grid, like in this excel screenshot below?

[image: table]

The code I have so far (**edit:** code was extracted from the [original inlined image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXGVi.png))

```java
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>(Customer.class);

grid.setColumns("datum", "lastName");
HorizontalLayout main = new HorizontalLayout();
grid.getColumn("datum").setWidth(100);
grid.getColumn("datum").setCaption("Datum");
layout.addComponents(toolbar, main);
updateList();

setContent(layout);
```

Current UI appearance:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)

Comment: @petey this question is about Vaadin, though. It might take several non-trivial steps to adapt css/html solution to Vaadin

Comment: @Ady96 you might want to specify which version of Vaadin you're using. If you have a code example (grid/table with regular headers) then post it as well.

Comment: @defaultlocale check my post now