# HTML/CSS : How to write a text vertically, keeping the characters horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if we could write a vertically text, but without use a rotation of any hacks that change the characters direction.

So, instead of "**START**", I want a text in may div displayed like this :
**S**
**T**
**A**
**R**
**T**

I could use "break-word: word-break" and set the width of my element to 0, but the text would'nt be centered. Characters will just be aligned to the left

**Not a duplicate of** : [Vertical Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)
I don't want to rotate the text, I want to preserve character's direction

Here is a code example of what I can get :

```css
.vertical-text {
    font-size: 25px;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
 }
 
 body, html {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%
 }
```

```html
<div class="vertical-text">START IT<div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)

Comment: I find wrapping each letter in a span very ugly, I won't loop throught my word / words to do that.. Moreover, a span with a space in will not display the space character. The solution posted by Abhitalks is what i was looking for

Comment: @MattewEon I was looking for the same as you. Write
S
T
A
R
T

But how does Abhitalks solution achieve that?
It makes it exactly rotated, not stacked as above

What do I miss?

Comment: OK here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136214/3934058

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use the [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) CSS property in conjunction with the [`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) CSS property.

```
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

To quote, `writing-mode` property..

> [..]specifies the block flow direction, which is the direction in
>   which block-level containers are stacked, and the direction in which
>   inline-level content flows within a block container. Content flows
>   vertically from top to bottom, horizontally from right to left. The
>   next vertical line is positioned to the left of the previous line.

In effect, this defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

`text-orientation` property defines the orientation of the text characters in a line. This property only has an effect in vertical mode.

**Example**:

```css
p:first-of-type {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
p:last-of-type {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<h4>With writing mode "vertical-lr"</h4>
<p>Start</p>
<hr>
<h4>With writing mode "vertical-lr" and text-orientation "upright"</h4>
<p>Start</p>
```

Be warned though about `text-orientation`:

> This is an experimental technology Because this technology's
>   specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for
>   usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of
>   an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of
>   browsers as the specification changes.

According to this: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-orientation, it seems *nearly* all browsers support it as of today, except IE/Edge.

Comment: Hey thanks @Abhitalks, it's totally what I was searching for ! I just have a small issue, if there is a space in the element all words will be stacked horizontally.  Is there a way to let a space between two words, like "START IT" ?

Comment: @MattewEon: it just works if the browser support it. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lgrxezmb/

Comment: Okay, I should have make a mistake. Thanks, it totally do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```css
.vertical-text {
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vertically Written Text</h1>

<h2 class="vertical-text">Vertical</h2>

<p>Tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 8, IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11.</p>
```

Comment: I said I know about word-break and width 0, but the text is aligned to the left and I want it to be centered

Answer (score -1):

Several ways to do it.

Check this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css--net-15284) out

**UPDATE**

Provide the best way to do it to me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Vertical Text</title>
 
<style>
  h1 span { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> START </h1>
   
  <script>
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    h1.innerHTML = '<span>' + h1.innerHTML.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could add some of those "ways" in your answer, as links may die any time, and save users a click