# Work-break not working on side-tab

Tags: css, tabs, antd

I'm working a simple tab menu using ant design, I want to display the text in the tab menu vertically.

```
T

A

B

1
```

My problem is, I cant achieve that state.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/3v19vkkn1p)

```
.ant-tabs-vertical > .ant-tabs-bar .ant-tabs-tab {
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)

Comment: I tried this too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: normal;` and deleting `line-height: 90px;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the writing-mode property as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction):

```
.ant-tabs-vertical > .ant-tabs-bar .ant-tabs-tab {
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

Comment: Should've left out the line-height as mentioned in my answer.