# How to type text vertically in Editable Fields with HTML, CSS, Javascript...?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to type text from up to down, right to left like the image below. I just search around but didn't find any result that matches my requirement. How can I do that with HTML, CSS, javascript? Thanks!

https://imgur.com/kO7BDbj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction)

Comment: @str no, my question is different. I don't want to show text in p, div or something else. I want to type text in textarea vertically.

Comment: have a look at the answer. You can use your div as an editable field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text-orientation` for the above quest the example is as follows:

```css
.some {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='some' contenteditable=true>
  some text <br>asdasdasdas<br> asdasdasdas<br> asdasdas<br> adasda<br> asdasd<br> adasda<br> adada
</div>
```

More details on the same can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

Comment: @SangramNandkhile Updated as per the comment.

Comment: @UllasHunka thank you, it's what I want. I haven't known that div has contenteditable attribute.

Comment: @MeoBeo Pleasure is all mine. Just FYI The contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not.