# rotating css grid item to create vertical text: how to expand the items new vertical height to fit text?

Tags: css, css-grid, css-transforms

I have a **jsfiddle** ready 
https://jsfiddle.net/1g8bc9ho/5/

I am trying to make a graph area. There is a title, plot, **yaxis** and xaxis area setup using **css grid**.

[image]

I rotate the **yaxis label**, but the text is wrapping itself. I want the yAxis label to expand to the maximum height of the plot area (which is variable depending on the plot!) Hopefully it can stay centered both vertically and horizontally, with the text expanding the entire row height.

```
//css
.PlotArea {
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 9fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.yAxis {
  background: dodgerblue;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: center;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.title {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.plot {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.xAxis {
    background: aqua;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
    text-align: center;
 }


/// html
<div class="PlotArea">
    <div class="yAxis">
        yAxis LAbel to Position
    </div>
    <div class="plot">
    <ul>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="xAxis">xAxis</div>
</div>
```

**How can I get the yaxis label to fill the plot height?** *...while keeping the first column fraction width the same? (Some methods I've tried change the width of the fraction and I don't understand why)*

Comment: Is this : https://jsfiddle.net/376ztcwb/ what you try to do ? (if not ff but for all : https://jsfiddle.net/376ztcwb/1/ ) or https://jsfiddle.net/376ztcwb/3/ or https://jsfiddle.net/376ztcwb/4/

Comment: Don't rotate it, use writing-mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction

Comment: I've never seen writing-mode before - and it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

@paulie-d provided part of the answer [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495817/rotating-css-grid-item-to-create-vertical-text-how-to-expand-the-items-new-vert#comment107025610_60495817): use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).

However, `writing-mode` offers two vertical options, viz. `vertical-lr` and `vertical-rl`, and in both, the text flows *"vertically from top to bottom"*, instead of the bottom-to-top orientation requested in the OP's example.

There *is* an experimental `sideways-lr` value, which *does* flow from bottom to top, but, unfortunately, that [only works in FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#browser_compatibility) at the moment.

One workaround is to combine `writing-mode` and `transform`, as mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894173), as follows:

```css
writing-mode: vertical-lr;  /* or vertical-rl */
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Although `rotate` doesn't affect the layout, `writing-mode` does. This  works in a variety of browsers.

Here's a snippet containing the OP's example with this modification:

```css
.PlotArea {
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 9fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.yAxis {
  background: dodgerblue;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: center;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;  /* MODIFIED */
  transform: rotate(180deg);  /* MODIFIED */
}

.title {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.plot {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.xAxis {
    background: aqua;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="PlotArea">
    <div class="yAxis">
        yAxis LAbel to Position
    </div>
    <div class="plot">
    <ul>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    <li>Plot Space Variable Height</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="xAxis">xAxis</div>
</div>
```