# Vertical text in IE7, IE8, IE9, and IE10 with CSS only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, vertical-text

Does anyone know how to successfully implement vertical text in IE7, IE8, IE9, and IE10 with CSS only?  (by vertical text, I'm referring to text being rotated counterclockwise 90 degrees)

This is what I have implemented today, which I think should be correct:

```
.counterclockwise-text {

/* Chrome/Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* IE9 */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* This should work for IE10 and other modern browsers that do not need vendor prefixes */
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* IE8 or less - using the "\9" CSS hack so that other browsers will ignore these lines */
zoom: 1\9;
writing-mode: tb-rl\9;
filter: flipv fliph;

}
```

However, IE10 is not ignoring the "\9" CSS hack -- it will pick up those values and rotate the text another 90 degrees.  A useful solution would be a way to do vertical text in IE8 and below that will not be picked up by IE10.  I really want to avoid having an IE8-only stylesheet, or having a media query to detect IE10.  I'm just looking for a way to modify the CSS above to have vertical text in all browsers.  Thank you!

EDIT:

For what it is worth, I also tried the code below that uses a filter to rotate the text.  This may work for most cases, but in my instance a lot of the text is cut off by the restricted (non-rotated?) constrains of the wrapping element.

```
.counterclockwise-text {

/* Chrome/Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* IE9 */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* IE10 and other modern browsers that do not need vendor prefixes */
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* IE8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

/* IE7 or less */
*zoom: 1;
*writing-mode: tb-rl;
*filter: flipv fliph;

}
```

I still have not found a way to do this with pure CSS where IE10 and IE8 are happy.

Answer (score 7):

Here is pure CSS ( + 1 extra div for every text ) solution

Works for all IE versions IE7-10

```
/** 
 * Works everywere ( IE7+, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera )
 */
.rotated-text {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1.5em;
}
.rotated-text__inner {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* this is for shity "non IE" browsers
       that doesn't support writing-mode */
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.1em,0) rotate(90deg);
       -moz-transform: translate(1.1em,0) rotate(90deg);
         -o-transform: translate(1.1em,0) rotate(90deg);
            transform: translate(1.1em,0) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
   /* IE9+ */
   -ms-transform: none;
   -ms-transform-origin: none;
   /* IE8+ */
   -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
   /* IE7 and below */
   *writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
.rotated-text__inner:before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

/* mininless css that used just for this demo */
.container {
  float: left;
}
```

HTML example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rotated-text"><span class="rotated-text__inner">Easy</span></div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="rotated-text"><span class="rotated-text__inner">Normal</span></div>
     </div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="rotated-text"><span class="rotated-text__inner">Hard</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

source: https://gist.github.com/obenjiro/7406727

Comment: Works well.  I tested from IE5, IE7-IE11.

Answer (score 2):

You should use conditionnal comment for older IEs .
That what they are meant for and it will do no hurts nor hack *(ing head)* s :)

Comment: I understand that conditional comments may be a better solution overall, but I asked for a solution using pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, but with additional bad readability of the rotated text, I would advice not to use the:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`

for IE9 or IE 8.

That's, what worked for me:

```
p.css-vertical-text {
    color:#333;
    border:0px solid red;
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
}
```

from http://scottgale.com/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/