# Vertical (rotated) text in HTML table headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, text-styling

My table headers are much wider than the data in the table, so I am trying to rotate the text in the headers to save space.

I've been trying out the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272799/vertical-rotated-text-in-html-table), and I've also taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/css-text-direction-vertical) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser).

However, none of the answers seem to actually work: here is my attempt in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urfatty/nMhmS/587/).

---

The text can rotate, but the `<th>` elements don't resize properly, which was the whole point of trying to rotate the text.

Now that it's been 2-4 years since those questions have been asked, are there any new solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to select the `thead` and size the rows accordingly:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uo44ub6L/

CSS:

```
thead th {
    height: 130px;
}
```

Another method would be to use `rowspan="5"` to create a larger `th` but you would need to add some blank rows, and you would get the same effect. Either would work.

If you need to do this dynamically, you could use javascript to select the `th` and adjust the size on the span length and font size.

Comment: The width doesn't change though. The format is great, but now the third column is taking up way more width than it needs. And I don't want to hard code the width of the column, because if a `<td>` is wide, then the width should increase to accommodate.

Comment: Ok, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uo44ub6L/1/ This is super hacky, but you're resizing the span, so the containg th size isn't adjusted, and thus will increase based on their contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: mixed;`

this will get the work done for you , Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b89yp5uz/) of it .

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible without any browser specific transforms that you used in your attempt. Note that the wrapping span is required as of 2022 in order to get firefox in particular to center the rotated text within the column (webkit does this by default). I also suggest you rotate the text at a slight angle as demonstrated here as it (IMHO) makes it easier to read.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  #myTable td {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  th.r span {
    transform: rotate(185deg);
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  }
</style>

<table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th class='r'><span>Display</span></th>
    <th class='r'><span>Year made (TV?)</span></th>
    <th class='r'><span>Native Res</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:rgb(17, 85, 204);">Dell U2410 (game) </td>
    <td>2010</td>
    <td>1080p</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:rgb(17, 85, 204);">Dell U2410 (sRGB)</td>
    <td>2010</td>
    <td>1080p</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:rgb(17, 85, 204);"> Sony 40VL130 (game)</td>
    <td style="color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">2008</td>
    <td>1080p</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```